# Do the muslimah at the time of prophet qualify as female companions?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, sahaba

Sahabi as explained by majority of scholars is a person who met prophet, accepted Islam and died in the state of Islam.

I am hesitant to call the non mahrams, except wives of prophet as female companions.

Do all muslim females at the prophets time qualify as sahabi?

Answer (score 2):

The definition you are using does not differentiate between the amount of time they spent with the Prophet ﷺ. As such even if a person was in the presence of the Prophet ﷺ only once for a brief moment, they would qualify as his companion. There isn't any reason why non-mahram women could not fulfill this condition such as when giving their allegiance, or in prayers, sermons or when asking him questions or seeking his judgement on their cases etc.

Comment: Companion isnt the right translation of the word sahabi right?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to think them as not sahabi. Some female companions of prophet(s.a) used to accompany in the war also

> It has been narrated on the authority of Anas b. Malik who said that
> the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) allowed Umm Sulaim and some other women of
> the Ansar to accompany him when he went to war; they would give water
> (to the soldiers) and would treat the wounded.
> https://sunnah.com/muslim:1810

> And their Lord responded to them, "Never will I allow to be lost the
> work of [any] worker among you, **whether male or female; you are of one
> another.** So those who emigrated or were evicted from their homes or
> were harmed in My cause or fought or were killed - I will surely
> remove from them their misdeeds, and I will surely admit them to
> gardens beneath which rivers flow as reward from Allāh, and Allāh has
> with Him the best reward." [Quran 3:195](https://quran.com/3/195)